# Joint probability given joint probabilities of component event combinations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working with a multivariate normal distribution, and I want to calculate the joint probability of many events given the joint probability of combinations of the individual events.

The simplest example would be the following:

Can I calculate

> $P(A \cap B \cap C)$

given

> $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C)$, $P(A \cap B)$, $P(A \cap C)$, and possibly $P(B\cap C)$

?

All the events are correlated, and the correlations/covariances are known, as are the expected values.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually if you write like this, as you said, $A, B, C$ are events. I am not exactly sure if you really meant this, or you are saying you are given the marginal/joint pdf of all proper subset of the original random variables. Anyway, you only need all the first two moments and cross moments to completely characterize a multivariate normal. If you are given all these, then you know everything.

Comment: Excuse my terms, I'm probably not using them accurately.  When I write $P(A)$, I actually mean $P(A \le x)$. So $P(A \cap B)$ is actually $P((A \le x) \cap (B \le x))$. I am looking at the cumulative distribution function. In terms of the moments, I know the expected means and covariances, and so can calculate the cumulative joint distribution, but it is expensive to calculate. I was hoping to get the same number by using individual joint cumulative probabilities that are calculated along the way. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know enough to do it with set properties alone.   You would need to know $\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C)$ also.   Recall the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

${{\mathsf P(A{\cup}B{\cup}C)}}{~=~{\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-\mathsf P(A{\cap}B)-\mathsf P(A{\cap}C)-\mathsf P(B{\cap}C)+\mathsf P(A{\cap}B{\cap}C)}}$

So, no, you are going to need to use the properties of multivariate normal distributions.